# In C++, how do you mutate objects in containers (vector, list, unordered_map)?

Tags: c++

**Context:**
New to C++ here. I have a larger project where I have a classes A, B, and C.

- Class A has a field with type unordered_map<int, B>.
- Class B also has fields of class C which have fields of type set.

I want to mutate the B objects in the map because I don't want the overhead associated with immutability. I have tried doing this with map.find() and map.at(), but with both methods, the mapped objects are not mutated as evidenced by the behavior of subsequent calls. I didn't try indexing with [] because class B does not have a default constructor.

1. According to the VSCode C++ documentation (but oddly not the online docs), the pair returned by find has a copy of the value object, which is wrong for obvious reasons.
2. I tried using at(), which supposedly returns a reference to the value object. This results in the same issue with find(), unfortunately.
3. I then tried making my map with values of *B, but later, these objects would go out of scope and I assume deallocated resulting in a segmentation fault.
4. So I even tried changing my map to be of type <int, int> where the value is an index into a vector, which is where I found the problem to be general to containers as opposed to just maps.

I know I can do something like `map.at(i) = map.at(i).funcWithSideEffects();` but I'm not ready to accept that this is the *only* way to do this. For a procedural language with a concept of state (i.e. not-a-fundamentally-functional language), it seems bizarre that there would be no way to mutate a value in a map or container-type field.

**Long story short and minimum example:**
How can I mutate objects in a container field such as a vector?
Example:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Person
{
private:
    string first;
    string last;
    vector<Person> children;
public:
    Person(string first, string last) {
        this->first = first;
        this->last = last;
    }

    string getFirstName() {
        return this->first;
    }

    void setFirstName(string first) {
        this->first = first;
    }

    string getLastName() {
        return this->last;
    }

    vector<Person> getChildren() {
        return this->children;
    }

    void addChild(Person child) {
        return children.push_back(child);
    }

};

int main() {
    Person p("John", "Doe");
    Person child("Johnny", "Appleseed");
    p.addChild(child);
    Person grandchild("one", "two");
    p.getChildren().at(0).addChild(grandchild);
    p.getChildren().at(0).setFirstName("Mark");
    cout << "Name: " << p.getFirstName() << " " << p.getLastName() << "\n";
    cout << "No. Children: " << p.getChildren().size() << "\n";
    cout << "Child Name: " << p.getChildren().at(0).getFirstName() << "\n";
    cout << "No. Grandchildren: " << p.getChildren().at(0).getChildren().size() << "\n";
   return 0;
}
```

Desired Output:

```
Name: John Doe
No. Children: 1
Child Name: Mark
No. Grandchildren: 1
```

Actual Output:

```
Name: John Doe
No. Children: 1
Child Name: Johnny
No. Grandchildren: 0
```

Edit:
Unfortunately, the example I created is decoupled from my original problem. Yes, the behavior that I want is that of references, which is why I was scratching my head when I used `map.at()`, which says it returns a **reference**. As described above, this is not the behavior I am observing. Leaving this solved, since I did a subpar job asking my question, and will construct a better example in a different post.

Edit 2:
Thank you to everyone who responded! I put two and two together and figured out what I was doing wrong in my map problem. 
I was accessing values in my map with

```
B b = map.at(i);
```

instead of

```
B& b = map.at(i);
```

I guess the original version makes a copy instead of retaining the reference that map returns. Will make a solution post if anyone else is confused about the same thing in the future.

Comment: If you have any array or vector (or map) `a` of `Person` elements, and a valid index (or key) `i`, then `a[i]` is a `Person` object which you can use as any other object.

Comment: Change `vector<Person> getChildren()` to `vector<Person>& getChildren()`. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/1Keer3M9o. Now, you are returning and then working with a copy of `children`. Either this is a typo or you should learn about references.

Comment: _"According to the VSCode C++ documentation (but oddly not the online docs), the pair returned by find has a copy of the value object..."_ — `find` returns an iterator, not a pair.

Comment: You need to learn about the differences between returning by reference and returning by value.   Your code is returning objects by VALUE, which means the returned object is a copy - so changing it does not affect the original.   You are seeking behaviour consistent with returning by REFERENCE, so the returned object is actually a (reference to) the object you want to modify.

Comment: VSCode doesn't come with any C++ documentation. You must have installed some kind of package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You returning a copy of your child with calling

```
vector<Person> getChildren() {
    return this->children;
}
```

With this, your **changes** are **done at the returned copy** only. **Not** in the original stored inctance.

Use a reference to it and you get the

```
vector<Person>& getChildren() {
    return this->children;
}
```

with this you do the changes in the stored instance.

I you want to avoid useless data copy work, you could change

```
void addChild(Person& child) {
    return children.push_back(child);
}
```

That avoids creation and deletion of instances to/from the callstack.